# Design pattern to accommodate two different ways of handling a Winform's functions

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I have a `WinForm` that I have used to build and test an email newsletter. This form contains a number of methods and events.

I am now adding a new feature to my program to allow split testing (A/X Test) and therefore creating up to 4 different newsletters for a campaign.

Therefore I'd like to extend my form to accommodate both normal newsletters and A/X newsletters. I'm going to add two different modes to my form. Something like:

```
private enum CampaignMode { Normal, AxTest };
```

They will be very similar in appearance, except a number of controls' visibility will change.

Apart from that, almost all methods and events will have two separate ways of handling.

What design pattern should I use so that I don't have to create a new separate form?

For simplicity, let's say my form has the following methods:

1. **Constructor**: probably receiving the `EditMode` as a parameter
2. **Load**
3. **Create**: Button click event
4. **SetControlViews**: Based on `EditMode` set the visibility of controls
5. **MethodA**: Specific to `Normal` mode
6. **MethodB**: Specific to `AxTest` mode

Comment: Have you considered something like MVP? The form could be abstracted to a view interface and then have two implementations (presenters?).

Comment: @DavidOsborne the problem is, this form is only a small part of a big program. It probably would have been nice to apply `MVP` in the beginning. But I guess, unless I do a complete overhaul of the program, applying the framework partially will not do me any good.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could still take the IView concept and have two 'pluggable' implementations. It doesn't need to be strictly MVP for you to create a neat and SOLID solution.

Comment: @DavidOsborne could you please be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply have pairs of functions for each method/event and then have the main handler call the appropriate one, depending on the value of CampaignMode.

```
public enum CampaignMode { Normal, AxTest };
public partial class DemoForm : Form
{
    private CampaignMode campaignMode;
    public DemoForm(CampaignMode mode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        campaignMode = mode;
        SetControlsVisibility();
    }
    private void SetControlsVisibility()
    {
        if (campaignMode == CampaignMode.Normal)
        {
            //Set normal controls visible;
            //Set axtest controls invisible;
        }
        else
        {
            //Set normal controls invisible;
            //Set axtest controls visible;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (campaignMode == CampaignMode.Normal)
        {
            MethodA();                
        }
        else
        {
            MethodB();
        }
    }
    private void MethodA()
    {
    }
    private void MethodB()
    {
    }
}
```

Note: if there are many controls, then it is neater to have a visibility function with a bool parameter:eg

```
    private void SetNormalVisibility(bool isNormal)
    {
        //normalTextBox.Visible = isNormal;
        //normalButton.Visible = isNormal;
        //axTestTextBox.Visible = !isNormal;
        //axTestButton.Visible = !isNormal;
    }
```

In which case, change the SetControlsVisibility function to:

```
    private void SetControlsVisibility()
    {
        if (campaignMode == CampaignMode.Normal)
        {
            SetNormalVisibility(true);
        }
        else
        {
            SetNormalVisibility(false);
        }
    }
```

HTH

Jonathan

Comment: I think this will eventually be what I do.

Comment: What happens when you add more `CampaignMode`s?

Comment: @Disasterkid So you were basically struggling with `if/else`! Everybody reading your question thought you needed real flexible design. I wouldn't call this if/else thing flexible enough. It's not SOLID. Interfaces are better approach.

Comment: If/else can be the reasonable solution when you know there are definitely only 2 cases by definition and it's all pretty simple stuff. However, if those 2 cases can easily become N cases, then some level of abstraction would go a long way.

Comment: @NikhilVartak you have a point. But I simply found the pattern too complicated compared to the size of my class.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) would be a good candidate.

Make a base class which takes care of logic for the basic initialization, `Load()`, `Create()`, `SetControlViews()` and then make `Method()` virtual and override in two derived classes according to specialized logic. Also, the constructor of each derived class could do some specialized initialization.

This way you don't even need a `CampaignMode` enum (or `EditMode` if you meant those to be identical). The existence of different entities there is illustrated by the existence of different derived classes.